# Application Alerts/Warnings not being suppressed when sub is called from another module/sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report I'm in the process of automating, there are a couple of modules, one containing all the Queries that get run, e.g Queries.SQLReport1 is the first sub, and then the report that gets generated using that data is in Reports.GenerateReport1.

I then have another Module called Main, whose contents is:

```
Sub ReportGeneration()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Queries.SQLReport1
Reports.GenerateReport1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Even though in my main sub, as well as the Query and reporting subs, I have `Display Alerts = False`, whenever a sheet is deleted, the Delete Sheet confirmation box pops up. This doesn't happen if running the individual sub itself, only when its being called by the main sub.

I guess I could put a pop up at the start that says 'Please confirm Delete whenever asked' but preferably they'd be supressed. Is there anyway to globally suppress the warnings until all the subs being called are run?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. The only thing I can think of is that the first sub can have `Application.Displayalerts = False` somewhere at the end of it, and it doesn't get reapplied before the next sub is called. Best practise would be to remove all these declarations from your subs, and only rely on the ones in this sub instead.

Comment: If you don't get the prompt when running the individual routines, there must be code in those routines that turns off `displayalerts`? It would probably help if you posted **all** of the code.

Comment: They're quite long subs, to keep it simple, imagine I have Module1.Main, and Module2.SheetSub, and in Module2.SheetSub all I have ````DisplayAlerts = False```` and ````Sheets.Add.Name = "TempData````, ````Worksheets("TempData").Delete```` and ````DisplayAlerts = True````. If I run SheetSub by itself, the sheet is deleted without warning, if I call it from Main, the warning is displayed.

Comment: If your called subs handle displayalerts properly, why do you need to do anything with it at all in the main sub?

Comment: You shouldn't need to, but I tend to put it in every sub out of habit. Turned out just to be some weird quirk with the workbook/excel, created a new workbook, copied over all the code, not a single character difference, but this time it worked as desired.

Answer (score 0):

So I created a new Workbook, made new modules, and copied and pasted all the code into the new modules, without changing a single line, but now it works. I am going to chalk this one up to freak bug, but appreciate people who commented/answered.